# Getting HttpContext.Current as null after await/async in Task.Run

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to execute a method in C# with "Fire and forget" approach using `Task.Run`. Within `Task.Run` whenever I execute another `async` method with `await`, then `HttpContext` becomes `null`. Please let me know if there is a way to preserve `HttpContext` while running `async` methods inside `Task.Run`.

Example code:

```
public virtual async Task AddAsync(TModel item)
{
    // Copy HttpContext to use in Task.Run
    var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current?.Request;
    var httpResponse = HttpContext.Current?.Response;
    var contextItems = HttpContext.Current?.Items;

    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var taskContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

        if (contextItems?.Keys != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in contextItems.Keys)
            {
                taskContext.Items.Add(key, contextItems[key]);
            }
        }

        HttpContext.Current = taskContext; // Context gets copied here correctly.

        try
        {
            await this.InsertAsync(item);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error
        }
    });
}
```

```
public virtual async Task InsertAsync(TModel item)
{

    var contextBeforeAwait = HttpContext.Current;  // This is not null
    await this.DoAsyncWork();
    var contextAfterAwait = HttpContext.Current; // Context here becomes null

   // Remaining Insert logic which needs to use HttpContext.Current
}
```

Web.config has:

```xml
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

Please let me know how to avoid this issue and preserve the `HttpContext` after async/await calls in `Task.Run`.

Comment: If you are getting null than the connection never completed and you getting a timeout exception.  There is no way of preserving the HttpContext when there is no response from a timeout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to execute a method in C# with 'Fire and forget' approach using Task.Run.

Are you sure that's what you want? I just ask because in >90% of cases where people *think* they want fire-and-forget, it's actually the wrong solution for their use case.

Specifically, fire-and-forget means "I don't care if this code sometimes isn't run, and I don't get any logs or notification of any kind about it not running." It's OK for things like updating caches, but really bad for things like updating database records.

> Within Task.Run whenever I execute another async method with await, then HttpContext becomes null. Please let me know if there is a way to preserve HttpContext while running async methods inside Task.Run

No, there is not. In fact, you're not supposed to access any `HttpContext` properties or methods from another thread at all. In other words, *no* code inside a `Task.Run` should access `HttpContext` *at all*. The fact that part of it works is purely accidental (and it can fail at runtime in production if the timing is different).

The more proper solution is to copy everything you need out of `HttpContext` first, and *then* start the background work, passing in that copy of the data.